# ClearCase: How to list history of elements with attribute events

Tags: clearcase

How to list history of elements with attribute events?
If I use "`-minor`", then all the minor events are listed but I want the attributes attached to each version of the elements only.

For example, the following will be an ideal result:

```
\feecalc-jcc\test.txt  \main\1  mkattr  Added attribute "FIXES" with value "NONE".
\feecalc-jcc\test.txt  \main\1  mkattr  Added attribute "FIXES" with value "CJA-1".
\feecalc-jcc           \main\2  checkin Added file element "test.txt".
```

With -minor I got a lot more like:

```
\feecalc-jcc\test.txt       protect CHOWN vobadm
```

Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the way [`lshistory` (man page)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lshistory.htm), the simplest way would be to still use `-minor`, and "`grep attribute`" the result.

> `–min/or`
>   Includes less important events in the listing: **attaching of attributes**, version labels, and so on. For type objects and storage pools, minor events include rename operations and changes to pool parameters (`mkpool –update`).

That option is the only one with attribute-related event mentioned.